# Combine txt files with file names

Tags: python, concatenation

I want to combine txt files into a single txt file. The code below works fine. But the only problem is that I don't understand which strings came from which txt.

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I want to result to look like:

```
file1.txt
string1
string2
file2.txt
string3
string4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works exactly as I want it to. First, I tried printing the f variable holding the file name. `outfile.write(f)` But since I opened the file in "rb" mode, I got the error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. I changed the code to `outfile.write(f.encode())` upon my friend's suggestion. Here, I don't know what the `encode()` method does. *Maybe someone explains.* Then, I used `outfile.write("\n".encode())` to start a new line after the filename. The final code is:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(f.encode())
            outfile.write("\n".encode())
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pickle` to `dump` the file name to `result.txt`

```py
import glob
import pickle

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open("abc.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            pickle.dump(f, outfile)
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

You can use `dump` for the outfile.write() part as well like this:
`pickle.dump(infile.read(), outfile)`

**NOTE: Preferably use `.dat` for binary files and `.txt` for plain text files.**

Comment: It worked but there are a few problems. First, there is nonsense characters before filename. Second, there is a dot after filename and the first string does not start at the beginning of the line. Results is [link](https://i.ibb.co/h2sNKqc/3980.png), I want to look like: [link](https://i.ibb.co/rQ1vmR5/6198.png)

Comment: The formatting is not what it looks like. That is a binary file so it is not stored like plain text. The only way to read it is through code. If you want it to be formatted like https://i.ibb.co/rQ1vmR5/6198.png then I suggest using a `txt` file.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I could not understand what is non-plain text file. All files in folder are txt files and their content is only plain texts.